# Quickbook web connector 403 error

Tags: web, quickbooks, connector, qbxml

HI i am php for quickbooks enterprise data exchange from web connetor.
I am getting this error when i do customer query.

QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed Error message: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with QuickBooks.

Your web server is throwing a `403 Forbidden` error message. Fix your web server so it doesn't throw `403 Forbidden` errors.

Comment: The remote server where the quickbook is installed ?

Comment: No the remote server that the Web Connector is connecting to. e.g. your web server.

Comment: If you look in the logs (or post them) you'll see the URL in them. You may also get more info by setting the QuickBooks Web Connector to VERBOSE mode.